# Listening to update within a function

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I've got a https onRequest cloud function that writes a doc. That doc triggers another cloud function, which adds a field to the doc based on a calculation.

Any suggestions how to make the res of the https onRequest function to wait until that field is added and to respond to the https with the value of that field?

```
exports = module.exports = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {

    const user = await admin.firestore().collection("users").doc();

    const enquiryId = await admin.firestore().collection("users").doc(user.id).collection("enquiries").doc();

     await enquiryId.set({
       value: req.query.value;
    });

    let getQ = functions.firestore.document('users/{user.id}/enquiries/{enquiryId.id}').onUpdate((change, context) => {
      const newValue = change.after.data();
      q = newValue.quote;
      return q
    });

    getQ;
    return res.status(200).send(getQ);
});
```

Comment: Firstly, you can't use `functions.firestore...` inside another function.  The functions SDK is only for defining functiton triggers, not for executing queries.  You will have to use the Firebase Admin SDK for that, as you are already for the first query.  Once you have that working, just send the response from the listener function when it fires.

Comment: Thanks - yes, i've been trying to find an example of a listener for an admin function, but only found functions...onUpdate. How does the fb admin sdk listener look like?

Comment: Have you examined the documentation?  There are examples for a variety of environments.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen

Comment: @DougStevenson yes, i have, but didn't see an example of a res being triggered onUpdate. It's all about on snapshot there...

Answer (score 0):

**Update following your comments below:**

Since the "cloud function gets triggered when we write to the firestore from mobile or web" you could set up a listener to the `users/{user.id}/enquiries/{enquiryId.id}` document.

You just have to send back the values of `user.id` and `enquiryId.id` as response to the HTTP Cloud Function, as follows:

```
    await enquiryDocRef.set(data);
    return res.status(200).send({userDocID : user.id, enquiryDocId: enquiryId.id});
```

and you use these two values to set the listener. The doc is here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen

This way, when reaching step 4 described in your comment, i.e. when "based on the calculation, a field in the (`users/{user.id}/enquiries/{enquiryId.id}`) doc gets updated", your listener will be triggered and you will get this updated field value in your front-end.

---

**Initial answer:**

If you want the HTTP Cloud Function to "wait until that field is added and to respond to the https with the value of that field", you just have to wait that the asynchronous [`set()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#set) operation is completed before sending back the response.

You can detect that the operation is completed when the Promise returned by the `set()` method resolves.

Since you do `await enquiryId.set({...})` **you are therefore very close to the solution**: `await` will make the Cloud Function wait until that Promise settles (is not pending anymore), so you just have to return the response right after this line, as follows:

Therefore just do as follows:

```
exports = module.exports = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {

    try {
        const userDocRef = await admin.firestore().collection("users").doc();
        const enquiryDocRef = await admin.firestore().collection("users").doc(userDocRef.id).collection("enquiries").doc();

        const data = {
            value: req.query.value
        };

        await enquiryDocRef.set(data);
        return res.status(200).send(data);
    } catch (error) {
        return res.status(400).send(error);
    }

});
```

Comment: thanks, but that's not the issue. To explain it simpler, let's look at the steps required: 1) https onrequest => 2) doc is created => 3) another cloud function is triggered that calculates something => 4) based on that calculation, a field in the doc gets updated => 5) https res responds with that field's value. 
The docs on firestore are silent on how to await an onupdate of a field from within a function or I couldn't find it anywhere.
your code is waiting for 2), while the issue is how to await 4) and respond with the result via https res

Comment: Ok, I understand better now! From where do you call the Cloud Function? From a front-end (an Android, iSO or Web app)? Or from another server?

Comment: The cloud function gets triggered when we write to the firestore from mobile or web

Comment: thanks for the update, i like this line of thought, but what's still a challenge is that the front-end is someone else's - so i can't put a listener on their end. They just want to hit my url and receive a ready response with the value... So i need to find a way to listen to the change on my end somehow...